# SSIS extract string between characters

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have following columns in my source SQL table

```
**Name**  |**Locations** 
----------------------------
Tom       |;1500002;3940000;49599;'USA';
<p>Gerry  |;100000;23;45222;3445;'Canada';4245;'Australia';'Singapore';
```

I need to extract string between single quote ' and add new row as shown below using SSIS.

```
**Name**|**Locations**
------------------------
Tom     |USA
Gerry   |Canada
Gerry   |Australia
Gerry   |Singapore
```

Please let me know how do I achieve it.

Comment: Are the list of valid values finite? Because the easiest thing to do would be to join to a table which lists all the valid values. That would pick out only the values that are valid (i.e. exclude numerics) _and_ generate multiple rows for you.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a CROSS APPLY and virtually any Split/Parse function

**If 2016 You can use String_Split()**

```
Select A.Name
      ,Locations = substring(B.Value,2,len(B.Value)-2)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply String_Split(A.Locations,';') B
 Where B.Value like '''%'''
```

**If not 2016**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Name varchar(25),Locations varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
('Tom',';1500002;3940000;49599;''USA'';'),
('Gerry',';100000;23;45222;3445;''Canada'';4245;''Australia'';''Singapore'';')

Select A.Name
      ,Locations = substring(B.RetVal,2,len(B.RetVal)-2)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Locations,';') B
 Where B.RetVal like '''%'''
```

**Both would Return**

```
Name    Locations
Tom     USA
Gerry   Canada
Gerry   Australia
Gerry   Singapore
```

**The UDF if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as X
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

Answer (score 0):

First at all, this kind of operation **doesn't need to be done with SSIS** you can do it using a Simple SQL query. *(Like @JohnCappelletti Suggested)*

But this way you can do it using SSIS:

*First at all add your OLEDB connection managers*

1. Add a DataFlowTask
2. in the DataFlow Task add an `OLEDB Source` --> `Script Component` --> `OLEDB Destination`
3. In the `Script Component` mark `Location` column as input and add an ouput column `OutLocation` with similar type and length to your input
4. In The Script Write The Following Code:

   ```
   If Not Row.Location_IsNull AndAlso _
      Not String.IsnullOrEmpty(Row.Location) Then

      Dim strTemp = Row.Location.Substring(0,Row.Location.IndexOf("'") - 1)

      strTemp = strTemp.Substring(0,strTemp.Index("'") - 1)

      Row.OutLocation = StrTemp

      Else

      Row.OutLocation_IsNull = True

   End If
   ```
5. Map `outLocation` to your Destination Column in the `OLEDB Destination`